# Image accessible from 2 URLs in Wordpress (www and non-www content duplication)

Tags: php, wordpress, duplicates

I have noticed that by default, Wordpress creates duplicate URLs to access the same image (www and non-www). For instance, visit this post:

http://www.shoutmeloud.com/blog-post-hacks.html .

Now copy the URL of the first image. It's http://www.shoutmeloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/optimize-images-min.jpg

Now, you will notice that the same image is also available at http://shoutmeloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/optimize-images-min.jpg

I think this is a case of content duplication in the eyes of Google. How to resolve this issue in Wordpress?

Comment: It's not an issue in wordpress, this is to let you choose your preference and google will honor it.

Comment: I'm sorry.. But I didn't get it. Isn't this the same as: http://www.example.com and http://example.com. If the redirection is not there, Google will consider is content duplication. Right?

Comment: Both www and non-www are equal. It's for you to choose or select which url you would like to register under google webmaster tool. Equal including SEO.